# Generating random evenly divisible numbers within a specific range in C++?

Tags: c++, random

I'm making a Flashcard program for 5th graders to practice their math skills.  Whenever they get to the division part of the program, it does not generate evenly divisible numbers.  I've generated two numbers like so:

```
    int divisor_one = 1+rand()%5 * 2;
    int divisor_two = 1+rand()%5 * 2;
```

I thought by multiplying it by two, it gives only even numbers but I was wrong.  It generates a 5, as seen below.

```
    ********************************
          Division Flashcards
    ********************************
                  3
                  5
              _____
```

Clearly, these two numbers are not evenly divisible.  How can I generate random **evenly divisible** numbers?

Comment: Seems like you multiply the random number by 2 and then add 1. `(1+rand()%5) * 2;`might work better.

Comment: That does make it generate only even numbers, but it does not make them evenly **divisible**.

Comment: `>>but it does not make them evenly divisible` what is evenly divisible number then?

Comment: 8 divided by 4 is 2.  10 divided by 5 is 2.  6 divided by 3 is 2.  Numbers that, when divided, don't generate a floating point number.

Comment: Make one of them the answer instead and the other either the bottom or top divisor. And use them(multiply them with eachother) to get the second divisor.

Comment: Bo's method generates evenly divisible numbers then. I have: 4, 6, 10, 2 generated. Evenly divisible or not?

Comment: I might have interpreted "evenly divisible" as "even". If you want a number divisible by `x` you could multiply by `x` instead of by `2`.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed to code to 
        int divisor_one = (1+rand()%5) * 2;
        int divisor_two = (1+rand()%5) * divisor_one;
It worked after the change.

Comment: c++ operator precedence means the "+1" happens last. So all your results will be odd. I am concerned that you don't think '3' is an odd number. I don't believe that evenly divisible has anything to do with even numbers - a number is evenly divisible by another if there is no remainder after division. So, generate two numbers, multiply them, show the result and one of the numbers and the other number is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I had in mind:

```
int divisor_one = 1+rand()%5 * 2;
int result = 1+rand()%5 * 2;
int divsor_two = divisor_one * result;
```

That way you make sure the result is always an even product of whatever the factors are.